# Combining c = c & (1 << bit) and int c = passkey.charAt(i % passkey.length() in a Challenge

Tags: java, int, bit

I'm breaking my head over this :

```
    for(i=0; i<message.length(); i++) {
        int c = passkey.charAt(i % passkey.length());
        int d = message.charAt(i);

        c = c & (1 << bit);

        result = result + (char)(c ^ d);    
    }
```

I know that LyJwNh9iPil3 (message) translates to ENCRYPTED (result). What I can't figure out, is what the used passkey should be. Currently, I'm stuck at :

L = 76
E = 69
so result char = 69, so c must be 69^(1/76) = 1,05729... But that is AFTER the x-th few bits are chewed off, and after the division by the password length.

I believe I will never be able to solve this, the path I'm going. Can you confirm that? The number of letters in the message and the result is different, right?

Comment: If you have posted the correct code, then -- `c = c & (1 << bit)` clears all but one bit of `c`, and thereby removes most of the information about `passkey`. For example, this code will give the same result if `passkey = "ABC"` as it will if `passkey = "abc"`, unless `bit` just so happens to be `5`. So, at most, you can only ever reconstruct one bit from each character of `passkey` (viz., whichever bit `bit` is).

Comment: Actually, I can go further, and say that -- unless I'm missing something -- you definitely have not posted the correct code. `'L'` is `0100 1100` and `'E'` is `0100 0101`, so `c` would have to be `0000 1001`, which is impossible: `c = c & (1 << bit)` ensures that it has only one bit set to `1`.

Comment: By the way, you seem to be thinking that `c ^ d` means "`c` to the power of `d`"? That's not the case. In Java, and in other C-descended languages, `c ^ d` means "the bitwise XOR of `c` and `d`".

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong here:

```
69^(1/76) = 1,05729..
```

^ is bitwise XOR, not power.

Comment: I just learned that, yes.. :)

So, I'm on the wrong track here, I guess. :(